# How does the memo in #inject work?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use a `while` loop inside `#inject`. However, the last memo becomes nil at some point and I don't understand why. Here is my example (I use `#each` on the example just to show the expected result):

```
class TestClass
  BASE_ARRAY = [5, 1]

  def test_method(value)
    result = []

    BASE_ARRAY.each do |item|
      while item <= value
        result << item
        value -= item
      end
    end

    result
  end

  def test_method_alternate(value)
    BASE_ARRAY.inject do |memo, item|
      while item <= value
        p memo
        # memo << item (if left, returns NoMethodError for nil Class)
        value -= item
      end
    end
  end
end

solution_one = TestClass.new.test_method(11)
p solution_one # => [5, 5, 1]

solution_two = TestClass.new.test_method_alternate(11)
p solution_two 
# => [] 
     [] 
     nil
```

How does the accumulator become `nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `nil` initially from the [`while` loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-while+Loop):

> The result of a `while` loop is `nil` unless `break` is used to supply a value.

That result becomes the result of other statements in a chain:

```
while
-> do |memo, item|
  -> BASE_ARRAY.inject
    -> test_method_alternate(11)
      -> solution_two
```

---

To have `.inject` fill up an array, you'll want to provide an empty array to use as the first `memo`:

```
BASE_ARRAY.inject([]) do |memo, item|
# ...            ^^^^
```

Then, be sure the array is the result of the block:

```
... do |memo, item|
  while item <= value
    memo << item
    value -= item
  end
  memo # <---
end
```

Comment: Thanks, @jonathan! The `explanation` about the returned value of `while` helped a lot, plus returning the `memo`, that I didn`t know I had to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- You need to initialize the `memo` with a value, in this case, you'll want a `[]`.
- You need to return the `memo` on each iteration of `inject`.

So, you should get your desired result of `[5, 5, 1]` by changing your method to be like this:

```
def test_method_alternate(value)
  BASE_ARRAY.inject([]) do |memo, item|
    while item <= value
      memo << item
      value -= item
    end
    memo
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @paul! The lack of the memo value `[]` was a mistake when I typed the question, but I was not returning the memo, and that was the problem. Thanks for your help!